# LINQ Query on Datatable to check if record exists

Tags: c#, linq

I want to perform a LINQ query on a datatable called Records and check if a record exists. If it exists, I want to find out the row which it is in. How might I go about doing this?

I wanted to do a .where on my datatable after adding the system.linq namespace but the method didnt seem to exist. Please advise

P.S : Am using c# in vs 2010

Comment: You can use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) to check if record exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the method because `DataRowCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to use the `AsEnumerable()` extension:

```
var dataRowQuery= myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => ...
```

You might also need a project reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` for this to work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

DataTable is not default uses Enumerable. you have to convert to

```
  var result = from p in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
     where p.Field("ID") == 2
    select p.Field("Name");

   if(result.Any())
   {
      //do your work
    }
```

read this article for

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/01/26/querying-datasets-introduction-to-linq-to-dataset.aspx

getting understanding your to use `Field<T>`

Comment: @paradox p is the object of dataTable.AsEnumerable()

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table such as:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("rownum", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(String));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "a");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "b");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "c");
```

Then,

```
Console.WriteLine(
                dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<String>(1) == "d").FirstOrDefault())); // `1:= index of column
```

would result `-1` because `"d"` is not found. But,

```
Console.WriteLine(
                dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<String>(1) == "b").FirstOrDefault())); // `1:= index of column
```

would result `1`, representing the row where `"b"` is in.