# Check if value exists in dataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable with two columns *Author* and *Bookname*.

I want to check if the given string value *Author* already exists in the DataTable. Is there some built in method to check it, like for Arrays  `array.contains`?

Comment: LINQ? `table.Any(t => t.Author == author);`

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can use [`LINQ-to-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) with [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
String author = "John Grisham";
bool contains = tbl.AsEnumerable().Any(row => author == row.Field<String>("Author"));
```

Another approach is to use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx):

```
DataRow[] foundAuthors = tbl.Select("Author = '" + searchAuthor + "'");
if(foundAuthors.Length != 0)
{
    // do something...
}
```

---

> Q: what if we do not know the columns Headers and we want to find if any
>   cell value `PEPSI` exist in any rows'c columns? I can loop it all to
>   find out but is there a better way? –

Yes, you can use this query:

```
DataColumn[] columns = tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
bool anyFieldContainsPepsi = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .Any(row => columns.Any(col => row[col].ToString() == "PEPSI"));
```

Comment: Add these `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to reference and `using System.Linq;` to using class

Comment: Out of the two solutions, which would be faster?

Comment: @PaulAlexander: there isn't a great difference. But the old `DataTable.Select` syntax is limited whereas LINQ can use the full .NET framework or custom methods. So only if you are stuck to .NET 2 you should use `DataTable.Select`, otherwise i'd always prefer LINQ

Comment: If you care about performance and have large datasets, `tbl.Select()` is dramatically faster than the other approaches.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  - Great Tim. But if user don't know the column name but still want to get all rows which is matching the search value  how it can be done ?

Comment: @ChandanKumar use my second query where i use columns. But instead of Any use Where.

Answer (score 17):

You can use Linq. Something like:

```
bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<string>("Author").Equals("your lookup value")).Count() > 0;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
DataRow rw = table.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(tt => tt.Field<string>("Author") == "Name");
if (rw != null)
{
// row exists
}
```

add to your using clause :

```
using System.Linq;
```

and add :

> System.Data.DataSetExtensions

to references.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method.  You can us it like this.

```
if(myDataTable.Select("Author = '" + AuthorName.Replace("'","''") + '").Length > 0)
    ...
```

The Select() funciton returns an array of DataRows for the results matching the where statement.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the database as IEnumberable and use linq to check if the values exist.
check out this link

[LINQ Query on Datatable to check if record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093560/linq-query-on-datatable-to-check-if-record-exists)

the example given is

```
var dataRowQuery= myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => ...
```

you could supplement where with any