# How to use Contains using C#

Tags: c#, datatable, contains

I have DataTable with a primary key with multiple columns

```
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {dt.Columns["Name"], dt.Columns["Type"] };
```

Now I want to check if my DataTable dt contains (Adarsh, Developer)

I have to pass two values in Contains Method

I tried using the following which doesn't seem to work

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows(e.RowIndex); 
DataRow drNew = dt.NewRow();
drNew["Name"] = dr["Name"];
drNew["Type"] = dr["Type"];
drNew["Address"] = dr["Address"];

if(dt.Rows.Contains(drNew["Name"].ToString(), drNew["Type"].ToString())) //This gives me an error
{
}
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`DataRowCollection.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h39yfbd(v=vs.110).aspx) overload you want to use has a single parameter: `Object[] keys`, but you're trying to pass two arguments.

You have to pack the keys into an `Object[]`:

```
dt.Rows.Contains(new object[]{first_value, second_value})
```

---

If you think it's ugly, you could wrap it in a simple extension method like this:

```
public static class Extenstions
{
    public static bool Contains(this DataRowCollection c, params object[] args)
    {
        return c.Contains(args);
    }
}
```

which would enable you to call it the way you do, like

```
dt.Rows.Contains(first_value, second_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Select().

```
DataRow[] result = table.Select("Name = 'foo' and Type = 'bar'");
```

And then see if result count is greater then 0.

Comment: Linq is a valid answer, it probably should be more like `table.Rows.Any(...)`

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is much easier to accomplish a very similar result

```
string name = "Bill";
bool hasValue = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => 'value' == row.Field<String>("Name"));
```

..also a very similar question can be found here
[Check if value exists in dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703320/check-if-value-exists-in-datatable)